# set whole column background color dcc row on plotly dash

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I use following code:

```
app.layout = html.Div([dbc.Row([dbc.Col("left", width = 2, style={'background-color': '#ADD8E6'}), dbc.Col("right", width = 10)])])  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

Then, I get following pages:

How can I make the blue color extend to the whole left part? (right now it only fill one line.) Thanks.

[image: dash plotly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the `dbc.Row` with `style={"height": "100vh"}` as follows:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc




app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = html.Div([dbc.Row([dbc.Col("left", width = 5, style={'background-color': '#ADD8E6'}),
                                dbc.Col("right", width = 5),
                                ],
                               style={"height": "100vh"})],
                      )  


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output:**

[image]